# CSS only menu hover issue in Safari iOS 8.4.1

Tags: html, css

I've got a safari-specific problem with a hover effect probably related to the synthetic click vulnerability fix in iOS 8.4.1. When the user tries to click on a link there is no response.

The menu is a simple CSS-only menu. I have created a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/baad95e3/

```
#menu :hover ul {
right:auto; 
left:0;
}

#menu :hover ul ul {
left:-9999px; 
width:160px; 
padding-left:5px; 
background:none;
}

#menu li ul :hover ul {
left: 170px; 
right:auto;
}

#menu li ul li ul li a {
text-align:left; 
color:#000;
}

#menu li ul li ul li a:hover {
color:#000;
}
```

What would be a good workaround without losing the hover effect.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: @APAD1 The links in the submenu don't seem to respond on an iPad or iPhone iOS 8.4.1. using Safari.

Comment: Ok, yeah it must be specific to 8.4.1 because it's working fine on 8.4 Safari.

Comment: Ok, it is probably due that an 8.4.1 device requires a double tap, with 8.4 only one tap is needed.

Comment: I have tried menu li a:hover {opacity:1; filter:alpha(opacity=100);} as a workaround but without result. Anyone suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hacky but can work, did for me in some cases:

```
* { z-index: 0; }
```